# Can a c++ compiler and includes be in one drive (system drive) and the code files themselves (.cpp) be at another?

Tags: 18.04, gcc, c++

Can I use my home drive as a place where the compiler and its files (and includes) are placed/installed, but use a different drive for my c/cpp source files?

For example, gcc and includes are in `/usr/`, while source/code files are on another drive.

I tried importing the necessary includes using

```
#include "/usr/include/stdlib.h"
```

etc. but it didn't work because adding just stdlib wasn't enough and it showed:

```
cannot open source file "stdarg.h" (dependency of "stdio.h")
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, VSCode.

EDIT:
The problem was solved by manually adding the includes path to the configuration file, `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Comment: What was the error you got and here linux uses `/` root where every thing resides and start. You can have various partitions mounted on different folders but all still link to `/` root.

Comment: Please write how you solved you issue, or tick answer which help you instead of write an edit which said "solved"; it will help more further readers

Answer (score 4):

Don't specify absolute paths in the *include* directive! If you want to include header files from other locations than the default paths you can use the pre-procecessor’s `-I` flag, multiple times if necessary. Pretty much all modern C and C++ compilers have embedded pre-processors, so you can simply specify the flag in the normal compiler command line:

```
cc [options...] -I/your/header/search-path -I/another/header/search-path [more options...] [source files...]
```

For more info see the [GCC manual section on “Options for Directory Search”](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) or equivalent sections of your C or C++ compiler’s manual.

---

`make`-based build systems will typically pass pre-processor, C compiler, and C++ compiler flags via the `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, and/or `CXXFLAGS` environment variables respectively:

```
CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/your/header/search/path" make
```

If your project uses a different build system please consult its documentation.

---

You can ask more specific questions about compiler and build system instrumentation over on [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/) as they’d likely be off topic here.

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Answer (score 0):

On any linux system, the compiler gcc is typically installed in /usr/bin, while the standard library include files are usually stored in /usr/include.

You can create your project files in your own home directory, or any other directory you have rw access to. While source projects for distro packages are typically installed in /usr/src

You need to provide more information on any errors you get when asking for help, so people can give you proper advice. I'm assuming you have already installed the gcc package on your system.

I suggest you google for a suitable tutorial for developing c++ applications on linux, which would provide you with answers to a lot of issues you are likely to have as you start out, including but not limited to a suitable ide.